# How can I make a grid similar to iphone/ipads launcher screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, grid

I have seen a few grids made with UITableView but I don't really like how close together each cell is to the other. If there is a way of creating a grid system like the home screen on an iphone (the screen after it is unlocked) if would be great. I don't need an exact solution but a point in the right direction, maybe a set of libraries to look through would be great. I am running xcode 4.4.1

Thanks!

Comment: `UICollectionView` is in iOS 6 by default, but there are also libraries like `PSCollectionView` that simulate it under iOS 5-. Also, you can just start out writing your own view by beginning with an `UIScrollView`.

Comment: My solution was that I used a simple Scrollview and implemented some buttons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is UIScrollView has a paging mode (since could have more buttons than fit in the view).  It's covered here's in Apple ocs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html

If you use that, each 'page' would have n buttons/views that when clicked would call a protocol/delegate call back for the consumer with the data to handle and it would evenly layout the UIView/buttons across that page view.  Contact me if you want my sample.

You probably don't want to require iOS6 as a minimum requirement but if you do, you can do as H2CO3 suggested in the comment and us UICollectionview.  Here's a tutorial:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

There's also some open source launchers that you can look into their code.  Here's some (I'm sure there's more).

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/sespringboard

Code is at: https://github.com/sarperdag/SESpringBoard

Also: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/openspringboard

Answer (score 0):

Use `UICollectionView`. You can create grid type views using that. It is available in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you can target iOS 6+, use UICollectionView. It's one of the best new things in iOS for years and it will be as important as UITableView.

The layout you're asking for is only a few lines of code.

NSHipster has a good [explanation of UICollectionViews](http://nshipster.com/uicollectionview/) and Ray Wenderlich has a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12).

(There's lots of example code out there, but [here's a very simple example project](https://github.com/erikt/ETMultiSelect) I did recently for [another question involving UICollectionViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142124/set-border-in-uicollectionview))