# How to add border to UICollectionView content?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, border

I would like to add a border to UICollectionView content so it can move with scroll and fit collection conent. Anyone has any idea how to achieve it? So far I am able to add a border to the whole collection but it is not what I'm looking for (pic).[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142124/set-border-in-uicollectionview

Comment: This is about adding a border to cells not to collection

Comment: Are you really able to scroll with the number of cells as shown in the image? I think No. It only bounces. What happens when the number of cells exceeds than what is shown in the image?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have put a border to your collectionView.

If you wanna add a border to your cells, try this:

```
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor;
```

Before this, make sure your cells are configured.